# Declare Variable in Angular: Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am having trouble setting variables in Angular HTML. Here's the sample code:

```
            <div *ngIf="{{'article image' | translate}} 1; let articleImage1Alt" > 
            <img *ngIf="document.image_1 " [src]="document.image_1 " class="image-1 " alt="{{document.image_1_alttxt || articleImage1Alt }}"  />
```

The `if` statement in the alt attribute is to set the default value for alt text to be "article image 1". `articleImage1Alt` is the variable that I am setting. However, I got an error for this.
zone.js:522 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:

> ```
>             <div [ERROR ->]*ngIf="{{'article image' | translate}} 1; let articleImage1Alt" > 
>             <img *ngIf="document"): DetailComponent@29:21 Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'."
> ```

I was wondering how to fix it?

## Update

Here's the updated code according to Charles's answer:

```
 <div *ngIf="('article image' | translate) + ' 1'; let articleImage1Alt" >
                <img *ngIf="document.image_1" class="image-1" [src]="document.image_1" alt="{{document.image_1_alttxt || articleImage1Alt}}"   />
```

It doesn't return error anymore but the alt attribute is returning empty in the html.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is incorrect for including a pipe. You should not need the curly braces as * already indicates to Angular that it needs to process the value as expression. A corrected example is below.

`<div *ngIf="('article image' | translate) + '1'; let articleImage1Alt" >`

Comment: thank you for your answer. There's no error anymore, but the alt attribute is empty. So it means something is still wrong. I was wondering if calling the `articleImage1Alt ` in the `img` section is incorrect?

Comment: @superninja this is because of the `ngIf` on `document.image_1`   That removes the whole element from being displayed including the alt.   You may want to remove the ngIf so the alt text can be displayed

Comment: You mean removing the whole ngIf attribute as this? It is still not working.. `<div *ngIf="('article image' | translate) + ' 1'; let articleImage1Alt" >
                <img class="image-1" [src]="document.image_1" alt="{{document.image_1_alttxt || articleImage1Alt}}"   />`

Comment: And the value of `document.image_1` isn't resolving to anything?